# Is a Sort Code and Correspondent Bank information needed for ALL international wire tranfers to the United States?

Tags: banking, wire-transfer

I am supposed to have some funds wired to me from a Government Institution (International). I filled in the paperwork provided by my bank (Wells Fargo) and sent it to the institution. They requested information such as a sort code and a correspondent bank. However, when I went to the bank(Wells Fargo)for assistance in completing the paperwork, I was informed that Wells Fargo has no sort code as this is something used by British banks. I was also informed that there is no correspondent bank.

The institution has since contacted me asking me to fill in the wire transfer document (and to do so completely) in order for them to finish processing my application. I am unsure what to do. I am now nervous about the entire wiring situation as I am fearful of the funds ending up in the wrong place.

Any advice?

Comment: The UK institution only knows how to send to a UK bank - you need to ask Wells Fargo how to receive a GBP payment. I think you did not get into a part of Wells Fargo that understands international payments,

Comment: Show this 2016 PDF to a Wells Fargo branch and ask for the latest once. There is definitely UK Sort Code for the correspondent bank. https://www08.wellsfargomedia.com/assets/pdf/personal/foreign-exchange/incoming-international-wire-transfer-reference-guide.pdf